# Which prog language to use for a server/android app projects?

Tags: android, server

I am thinking of doing a server that will be some sort of a webpage (to display data) and also a server that can send information to android app.

I currently know a bit of c++ and python. And android java a bit more. I was allready looking at java and tomcat but not liking the idea...

What are the best metods to make a server that will be able to send data to mobile app.. I dont need to communicate both ways only that android app becomes information.

**EDIT**
Sory I wasn't clear enough. A server needs to acces services and get data from the APIs and then it will save it in db. But the part where this server needs to communicate with android app is unclear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to host a website that displays data, without the need for server processing / database, you might want to take a look at [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/). You will be able to host static web pages for free.

Else, I would recommend you to [learn PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/). Purchase a web domain and hosting, it usually comes with database for you to store data.

Comment: Sory I wasn't clear enough. A server needs to acces services and get data from the APIs and then it will save it in db. But the part where this server needs to communicate with android app is unclear for me.

Comment: I see, I would recommend you to learn PHP. You will have to purchase a web domain and hosting.
You can output text, JSON or HTML from your PHP server pages.
In Android, I would recommend using [OKHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for connecting to your server and reading the data.